# Why doesn't this partial render with UJS / jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

I'm trying to use jQuery to create posts with a form in my Rails 3 project. Here's what I have:

*look below for updated results*

create.js.erb:

```
$("#posts").prepend("#{render(:partial => 'posts')}");
```

layouts/application.html.erb:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'rails' %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
...
```

posts_controller.rb:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      # ...
      format.js
    else
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

When I submit the post form it puts text like `#{render(:partial => 'posts')}` where the post ajax should be.

EDIT:
by changing `create.js.erb` to:

```
$("#posts").prepend("<%= render(:partial => 'posts')%>");
```

I get this error in the terminal when I submit the form:

```
Rendered posts/_posts.html.erb (13.6ms)
Rendered posts/create.js.erb (80.4ms)
Completed   in 1631ms

ActionView::Template::Error (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each):
    1: <%- for post in @posts -%>
    2:   <div class="post">
    3:     <%= link_to post.title, post %>
    4:     <%- if post.name? -%> 
  app/views/posts/_posts.html.erb:1:in     `_app_views_posts__posts_html_erb___692646030_16112196__738457576'
  app/views/posts/create.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_posts_create_js_erb__431255654_16166988__591965598'
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:39:in `create'

Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (10.6ms)
Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (54.3ms)
Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (102.1ms)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing the erb tag:

```
$("#posts").prepend("<%=render(:partial => 'posts')%>");
```

It appears that you are trying to render the full set of posts again, and I assume that you really want to render a single post.  This would result in duplicate posts showing up.  No @posts variable was set in your create method resulting in that nil error.  You should create another partial called _post and render a single post within there.  Notice that the create method sets @post, but not @posts.  That is where your error is coming from, because @posts is nil.  The error is a bit misleading b/c you are using:

```
for post in @posts
```

I would recommend using the following syntax that is more widely using in Ruby (which has the same effect as "for"):

```
@posts.each do |post|
```

I think this railscast may help you.  Based on what you are showing here, I think Ryan is doing almost the exact same thing, but using a polling method instead of submitting a form.  Pay special attention to the part where he creates _comment.html.erb to render a single comment.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/229-polling-for-changes

Comment: I get an ActionView::Template::Error with this. I posted the output in my question.